# disabling mouse events and progress bar

Tags: events, webgl, xtk

**how can i disable the mouse events?**

i want to use very simple mouse events on meshes and slices of a volume and use some ajax-calls there so the integrated events are not needed.

**how can i disable the progress bar?**

i've read it somewhere...

**is there any kind of *reference* where i can see what commands are available?**

[the xtk library](http://goxtk.com)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the interactor as well as the renderer have config options

```
var r = X.renderer3D();
// to disable the progress bar
r.config.PROGRESSBAR_ENABLED = false;
r.init(); // the r.init creates the interactor

// to disable the mouse wheel interaction
r.interactor.config.MOUSEWHEEL_ENABLED = false;
// to disable mouse clicks
r.interactor.config.MOUSECLICKS_ENABLED = false;
// init the interactor again
r.interactor.init();
```

To get information on the API, visit http://api.goXTK.com. Unfortunately, the current API doc does not cover everything (f.e. the config options). So, look at the documented sources here: https://github.com/xtk/X/blob/master/io/interactor.js#L189